Java Swing returning exception when i try to use a customized cursor in a Red Hat environment
I've been having the following exception everytime I try to run anything containing a customized cursor in a java swing component:
Warning: cursor image loaded 32 32

[AwtExceptionHandler:45] Error in AWT#012
<|>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero
<|>at java.awt.image.ReplicateScaleFilter.(ReplicateScaleFilter.java:85)
<|>at java.awt.Image.getScaledInstance(Image.java:156)
<|>at sun.awt.CustomCursor.(CustomCursor.java:52)
<|>at sun.awt.X11CustomCursor.(X11CustomCursor.java:26)
<|>at sun.awt.X11.XCustomCursor.(XCustomCursor.java:27)
<|>at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.createCustomCursor(XToolkit.java:878)
...

The first line is a log I inserted that reads the loaded width and height, and it does return the expected numbers, but it returns the exception immediately after
It's a Red Hat 7.6 environment running java jdk 1.6, and for legacy reasons i cannot update it. In other similar environments with same settings (RHEL 7.6 and jdk 1.6) this error does not happen, which leads me to think it could be an environment variable problem, not a code problem.
I built a small example to show, this is the code
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    static JFrame frame;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("asmacs");
    private static final String BIG_CROSS = "big_cross.gif";


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        create();
    }
    
    public static JFrame create() {
        frame = new JFrame("teste");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setCursor(getCursorCross());
        return frame;
    }

    private static Cursor getCursorCross() {
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        int hotSpot;
        hotSpot = 32;

        BufferedImage image = null;
        try{
            image = ImageIO.read(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource(BIG_CROSS));
            int width = image.getWidth();
            int height = image.geHeight();
            logger.warning("cursor image loaded " + width + " " + height);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warning(" error loading image ");
        }
        return tk.createCustomCursor(image, new Point(hotSpot, hotSpot), "cross");
    }

}

The image is a 32x32 PX GIF.
Does anybody know how to fix this problems?

Hello Nom, welcome, the line "<|>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero" indicates that it is receiving an image of size “0” (it is not receiving anything), so I deduce that the path you are passing is not correct, it should be something like: "/resources/img.jpg ”, being resources inside the src folder.

Hello @marcePuente. In the log, that Nom shared, it is mentioned the size of image reader. According to AWT API, the return of function getBestCursorSize can be 0,0 if system doesn't support custom cursors (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getBestCursorSize(int,%20int)). So I think it is a configuration problem.

Hello @Caio, the message, can't be more clear must be non-zero...

@MarcePuente the code is receiving the image correctly, since when I run it in other environments, it works. Also, when there’s no image the code actually returns a -1. The environment is probably changing the width and height from 32 to 0 at some point and that’s what I can’t seem to figure out

@Caio, I apologize, you are right.

Returns:
the closest matching supported cursor size, or a dimension of 0,0 if the Toolkit implementation doesn't support custom cursors., As you can read in the page provided by Ciao, the method getBestCursorSize is returning “0,0”, either because it does not support customization, or because it is returning the closest supported value to the proposed one, it is recommended to send us values other than the supported ones, to avoid the latter conversion.

I'd tested both scenarios of errors on code. The first was error when file doesn't exists. The exception when file doesn't exists is something like this:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1362)
    at Main.getCursorCross(Main.java:37)
    at Main.create(Main.java:26)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.CustomCursor.<init>(CustomCursor.java:37)
    at sun.awt.X11CustomCursor.<init>(X11CustomCursor.java:26)
    at sun.awt.X11.XCustomCursor.<init>(XCustomCursor.java:27)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.createCustomCursor(XToolkit.java:878)
    at Main.getCursorCross(Main.java:45)
    at Main.create(Main.java:26)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)

Then I' teste the error when image size is 0,0. It is not conventional error once it is almost impossible to generate a 0 size image so I forced image size to 0,0 on code creating an BufferedImage object using size 0. The exception of this case is like this:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:999)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:352)
    at Main.getCursorCross(Main.java:38)
    at Main.create(Main.java:26)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.CustomCursor.<init>(CustomCursor.java:37)
    at sun.awt.X11CustomCursor.<init>(X11CustomCursor.java:26)
    at sun.awt.X11.XCustomCursor.<init>(XCustomCursor.java:27)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.createCustomCursor(XToolkit.java:878)
    at Main.getCursorCross(Main.java:45)
    at Main.create(Main.java:26)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
    

In my opinion both exception are different from the Nom question, so I'd tried to replace your version of java to openjdk1.8 assuming that AWT implementation didn't change too much between both versions. Using openjdk1.8 I was able to debug in low level and reached the native AWT method XlibWrapper.XQueryBestCursor, which produces the dimensions object used by tk.getBestCursorSize which is used inside the constructor of CustomCursor and then call, if it requires resize, the method Image.getScaledInstance from cursor image passing nativeSize variable (which was 0,0 in your case).
Problem is that on openjdk 8, and problably some version of jdk, when getBestCursorSize returns on any dimension, the CustomCursor ignores nativeSize and don't resize the image, keeping the dimension of original image. Your jdk version doesn't have this fix (https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8173853?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel). However you mentioned that this code worked on some system with same setup, so I just can think that XlibWrapper.XQueryBestCursor should not returns 0,0.
Debugging native awt library I found that the X11 XQueryBestCursor is called to provide this request and return the best size according to the display and root_window provided by Java. When I did C debuging using jdk1.6 I could reach same functions of X11, so I think you can have the same error.
That means you could reproduce your problem using those values of display and root_window (you can get those debuging) and running a C code like this:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<X11/Xlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   unsigned int ret_h;
   unsigned int ret_w;

   if(argc < 3){
      printf("ERROR: uses as %s [WIDTH] [HEIGHT].\n", argv[0]);
      return -1;
   }
   Display *dis = XOpenDisplay( NULL );
   Drawable drw = RootWindow(dis, DefaultScreen(dis));
   Status st = XQueryBestCursor(dis, drw, atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]), &ret_h, &ret_w);
   printf("Display %lld\nDrawable %d\nXQueryBestCursor (%u,%u)\nRet_code %d\n", (long long int) dis, (int) drw, ret_h, ret_w, st);
   return 0;
}

The same data you could have using this class on Java:
package sun.awt.X11;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class X11Information  {
    public X11Information() {
    }
    public void printInformation() {
        XToolkit.awtLock();
        try {
            long display = XToolkit.getDisplay();
            long rootWindow = XlibUtil.getRootWindow(0);
            System.out.println("Display " + display);
            System.out.println("RootWindow " + rootWindow);
            Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            Dimension bestCursorSize = tk.getBestCursorSize(32, 32);
            System.out.println("BestCursorSize " + bestCursorSize.getHeight() + "," + bestCursorSize.getWidth());
        }
        finally {
            XToolkit.awtUnlock();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        X11Information x = new X11Information();
        x.printInformation();
    }
}

So if both returned the same value for cursor size we can imagine that the problem is in XQueryBestCursor of lib X11 (which is documented in here https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libX11/specs/libX11/libX11.html#Creating_Recoloring_and_Freeing_Cursors).
I could not reproduce your error because X11 functions are very complex and it works fine on my environment, but depends on the answer of these tests we can look for other problems.
